# How to pull from a session, edit it and then reinsert it in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a cart controller. I am using Laravel's [Http Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session) to achieve this. However, I am getting this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>   Cannot use assign-op operators with string offsets
>
> Previous exceptions
>    - Illegal string offset 'quantity' (0)

This is my current code which is causing this error:

```
public function addOrUpdate(Request $request) {
    if(!isset($request->productName) && !isset($request->productId))
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Please fill in all the required fields.'])->withInput();

    # Init cart if not yet set
    if(!$request->session()->has('cart'))
        $request->session()->put('cart', []);

    # Pull and delete the old value
    $product = $request->session()->pull("cart.{$request->productId}", "cart.{$request->productId}");

    # If we managed to pull anything, lets increase the quantity
    if(isset($product)) {
        $product['quantity']++;
        $request->session()->push('cart', [$request->productId => $product]);
        var_dump($request->session('cart')); # Confirmation
        return true;
    }

    # Nothing was pulled, lets add it
    $request->session()->push('cart', [$request->productId => [
        'productName'   => $request->productName,
        'quantity'      => 1
    ]]);
    var_dump($request->session('cart')); # Confirmation
    return true;
}
```

When I do a `var_dump($product)` before I pass it through the `isset()` condition, it gives me a value of `string(6) "cart.1"`.

If I do a `var_dump(session('cart'))` before I pass it through the `isset()` condition, it gives me (with test data)

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [1]=> array(2) { ["productName"]=> string(3) "foo" ["quantity"]=> int(1) } } }
```

In Laravel's documentation,

**#Retrieving & Deleting An Item**

The pull method will retrieve and delete an item from the session in a single statement:

```
$value = $request->session()->pull('key', 'default');
```

How can I get the current product stored in the ID, remove it, edit it and then re-insert it because this seems to be returning the array I am trying to get.

**Update**

```
public function addOrUpdate(Request $request) {
    if(!isset($request->productName) && !isset($request->productId))
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Please fill in all the required fields.'])->withInput();

    # Init cart if not yet set
    if(!session()->has('cart'))
        session()->put('cart', []);

    $cart = session('cart');

    if(isset($cart[$request->productId])){
        # Pull and delete the old value
        $product = session()->pull("cart.{$request->productId}", "cart.{$request->productId}");

        # If we managed to pull anything, lets increase the quantity
        if(isset($product)) {
            $product['quantity']++;
            session()->push("cart.{$request->productId}", $product);
            echo 'Updated';
            dd(session('cart'));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    # Nothing was pulled, lets add it
    session()->push("cart.{$request->productId}",  [
        'productName'   => $request->productName,
        'quantity'      => 1
    ]);
    echo 'Added';
    dd(session('cart'));
    return true;
}
```

This now seems to be adding the correct information but never updating. Do I need to `flash()` the session at all?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here was the fact that the HTTP Session in Laravel is only used once. In order to keep the values, it is imperative to `flash()` or `reFlash()` the cart.

```
public function addOrUpdate(Request $request) {
    if(!isset($request->productName) && !isset($request->productId))
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Please fill in all the required fields.'])->withInput();

    # Init cart if not yet set
    if(!session()->has('cart')) {
        session()->put('cart', []);
        session()->flash('cart');
    }

    $cart = session('cart');

    if(isset($cart[$request->productId])){
        # Pull and delete the old value
        $product = session()->pull("cart.{$request->productId}", "cart.{$request->productId}");

        # If we managed to pull anything, lets increase the quantity
        if(isset($product)) {
            $product[0]['quantity']++;
            session()->push("cart.{$request->productId}", $product[0]);
            session()->reFlash('cart');
        }
    } else {

        # Nothing was pulled, lets add it
        session()->push("cart.{$request->productId}",  [
            'productName'   => $request->productName,
            'quantity'      => 1
        ]);
        session()->reFlash('cart');

    }
}
```

The only issue here is that if the user navigates any where else, the other routes do not reFlash the cart. So this must be implemented.

I achieved this by adding this line of code in the `boot()` method of my `RouteServiceProvider.php` file:

```
if(session()->has('cart'))
    session()->reFlash('cart');
```